# Target of assignment expands to non-language object in R2.14.2

Tags: r

I am new bee with respect to using R for analysis. I would really appreciate your support for solving the following query

```
data <- read.csv ("Barcode.csv")   
i <- 1
while (i < 41)
{
     barcode <- c(data $b[i],data $c[i],data $d[i],data $e[i],data $f[i],
                  data $g[i],data $h[i],data $i[i],data $j[i],data $k[i],
                  data $l[i],data $m[i],data $n[i],data $o[i],data $p[i],
                  data $q[i],data $r[i],data $s[i],data $t[i],data $u[i],
                  data $v[i],data $w[i],data $x[i],data $y[i],data $z[i],
                  data $Aa[i],data $Ab[i])
    "work"[i] <-barcode
    i < - i+1
}
j < - 1
while (i < 100)
{
     barcode <- c(data $b[i],data $c[i],data $d[i],data $e[i],data $f[i],
                  data $g[i],data $h[i],data $i[i],data $j[i],data $k[i],
                  data $l[i],data $m[i],data $n[i],data $o[i],data $p[i],
                  data $q[i],data $r[i],data $s[i],data $t[i],data $u[i],
                  data $v[i],data $w[i],data $x[i],data $y[i],data $z[i],
                  data $Aa[i],data $Ab[i])

    work [41] <-barcode
    z <- pairwise.t.test (work,paired = TRUE)
    dspres [j] <- z
    i <- i+1
    j <- j+1
}
```

Running this programme gives me following error **"Error in "work"[i] <- barcode : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object"**

Answer (score 2):

"work" is a literal character vector, you cannot assign to a subset of it. This is no more than

```
"work"[1] <- 1
```

Try removing the double quotes.  I'm ignoring the rest of your code since the error message refers to exactly where this particular problem here is.